# MoviePy don't works in .exe file made by AutoPyToExe/PyInstaller with hide console option

Tags: python, console, pyinstaller, exe, moviepy

I used AutoPyToExe to made an executable file from a .py, the executable works great but when I use the function "Windows Based (Hide Console)" don't work the MoviePy library.
When the console it's not hidded MoviePy works but when I hide the console MoviePy stop working and don't say any error and only happen with this library because everything else work normaly.

The option that doesn't work

[The option that MoviePy gives error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyJCf.png)

I want to do an app who convert videos formats, it's works but when I pass to .exe without console, don't work the conversion process. I'm using MoviePy and Python 3.10 in Windows 11

The conversion code it's simple, the process works but with when I pass to .exe without console stop working:

```
#code...
clip = moviepy.VideoFileClip(r"" + myPath)
result = moviepy.CompositeVideoClip([clip])
result.write_videofile(pathOnly + output, codec='mpeg4')
#code...
```

A video about my problem:
https://mega.nz/file/4aZWEL6R#2y4WPr7ZgR386wfyV1V4ZAcFodhwzaL4LfIaVLhN9S0

The conversion script don't works, I replicate the code here and gives me the same result:

```py
import moviepy.editor as moviepy
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
def run():
    clip = moviepy.VideoFileClip(r"" + r"C:\Users\migue\OneDrive\Desktop\promoVideo.mp4")
    result = moviepy.CompositeVideoClip([clip])
    result.write_videofile(r"C:\Users\migue\OneDrive\Desktop\promoVideo" + ".avi", codec='mpeg4')

Button(text="run", command=run).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

I tried without interface but gives me an error:

```py
import moviepy.editor as moviepy

clip = moviepy.VideoFileClip(r"" + r"C:\Users\migue\OneDrive\Desktop\promoVideo.mp4")
result = moviepy.CompositeVideoClip([clip])
result.write_videofile(r"C:\Users\migue\OneDrive\Desktop\promoVideo" + ".avi", codec='mpeg4')
```

[The error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f62XV.png)

Comment: How do you expect anyone to be able to help you when you only provide the lines of code?  Please post a [mre]

Comment: I’m going to put a video, because there is no code, it’s not fault of my program.

Comment: Create a runnable example that reproduces the same behavior you are experiencing.

Comment: I put the video and a simple exemple of my error

Comment: When you run the eve, do not double click it.  Instead open up a terminal in that directory and run `main.exe`.  Then perform the same actions over again, and you should  see error messages in the terminal.

Comment: If I open the program with the console, it's gives me the same result, don't apear any error and don't works

Comment: In this community is permited repost a question?

Comment: Only if you delete the previous question first.  Making an edit to your question will bump it to the top of the queue thoiugh

Comment: ok, I hope someone answer me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that it doesn't work in window/noconsole mode is because moviepy writes a lot of output to `stdout`, and when an executable is compiled in windowed mode, pyinstaller explicitly sets `sys.stdout` to `None`.

The solution is to explicitly reset `sys.stdout` to something it can write to, such as a buffer or an open file.  For example, at the top of your script add something like the following.

```
import sys

output = open("output.txt", "wt")
sys.stdout = output
sys.stderr = output
```

You will also want to close the output file when closing the app window.

Comment: @MigueldeHaroce  see new answer

Comment: Ok, When I'm at home, I'll check it